# ruby : use credentials.yml.enc on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm new to the Ruby environment, and I wrote a ROR app that works fine locally.
I'm now trying to deploy it on Heroku, but it seems that it does not load my credentials.yml.enc, since the app crashes with a

> undefined method `dig' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

which is related to my line

```
Rails.application.credentials.odesli.dig(:api_key)
```

So it seems that Rails.application.credentials didn't load.

Any idea of how I have to handle this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that I had to [set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49663736/782013) var...

```
$ heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=123456789
```